# Uniqueness of Lie algebra structure of quotient under canonical projection mapping.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, and $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ a Linear subspace which is an ideal. That is, for every $X \in \mathfrak{h}$ and every $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, one has $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{h}$.

(i) Explain why every ideal is a Lie subalgebra.

(ii) If $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal prove there exists a unique Lie algebra structure such that the canonical projection map

$$\pi : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g} / \mathfrak{h}$$

is a Lie algebra homomorphism.

**Attempt:**

For (i), we just need to show $\mathfrak{h}$ is closed under the bracket operation, but if $X,Y \in \mathfrak{h}$, then $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ and as $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal, one has $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{h}$. Thus $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra.

For (ii) I am a bit more lost, so is this saying, given $\pi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, then show the brackets operation is unique. Does this resort to showing $\pi$ is well-defined? Because I know $\pi$ is a homomorphism iff for all $X,Y \in \mathfrak{g}$, one has

$$\pi[X,Y]_\mathfrak{g}=[\pi(X),\pi(Y)]_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}}.$$

I.e., if you apply $\pi$, then brackets its the same as applying bracket then $\pi$. This holds iff

$$[X,Y]_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}}=\pi([\pi^{-1}(X),\pi^{-1}(Y)]_\mathfrak{g}).$$

Also, this may be silly, but $\pi$ sends $g$ to the equivalence class $g+H$, correct? Thanks for any hints or tips, I am new to diff geo.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez so is the posed answer incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write looks correct (you mean "$\pi$ sends $g$ to the equivalence class $g +\mathfrak{h}$"), but maybe it helps to rephrase it this way: For $\pi$ to be a homomorphism, as you say, we are forced to define

$$[X + \mathfrak h, Y + \mathfrak h]_{\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}} := [X,Y]_\mathfrak{g} +\mathfrak h$$

but for this definition to make sense (i.e. giving a well-defined bracket on the quotient), we need that for all $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2 \in \mathfrak g$:

$$\left(X_1 + \mathfrak h = X_2 + \mathfrak h \text{ and } Y_1 + \mathfrak h = Y_2 + \mathfrak h\right) \implies [X_1,Y_1]+ \mathfrak h = [X_2, Y_2] + \mathfrak h$$

This is what you want to check, using that $\mathfrak h$ is an ideal.

Comment: Yes, thats right, $g \mapsto g+\mathfrak{h}$. My mistake there. Im just used to using $H$ and $G$ for group as apposed to mathfrak.

Comment: Am I correct in stating, $X_1+\mathfrak{h}=X_2+\mathfrak{h}$ holds if and only if $X_1-X_2 \in \mathfrak{h}$? Just by defn of what it means to do arithmetic in cosets. I know $uK=vK$ holds iff $v^{-1}u \in K$. I was wondering if the analagous statement holds for $+$.

Comment: Am I on the right track if I say since $X_1-X_2 \in \mathfrak{h}$ and $Y_1-Y_2 \in \mathfrak{h}$, then $[X_1-X_2,Y_1-Y_2] \in \mathfrak{h}$.